# PHP Javascript Codeigniter datepicker condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datepicker

i have drop down list that linked to datepicker..but i want to make a condition on my datepicker,if dropdownlist value is selected year (ex. 2017),then the datepicker only shows 2017 date.it cant be changed to 2016 or 2018.here is my some of my code example.

```
**PHP View**
<select name ="year" id="year" class="form-control select2">
 <?php foreach($year as $value)
  {
   echo "<option value="$value['id_year'].">".$value['year']."</option>"
  }
</select>
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="form-control">

**Javascript**
$('$date').datepicker({
    format : "yyyy-mm-dd",
    autoclose:true
})
```

How did i put a condition based on selected year ? Thank You...

Comment: `echo "<option value=".$value['id_year'].">".$value['year']."</option>";`

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch changes on your select input,
then set the max and min Date of the datepicker

```
$('#year').on('change',function(){
   var year = $(this).val();

 $('#date').datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(year, 0, 1) );
 $('#date').datepicker("option","maxDate", new Date(year,11,31));
});
```

Comment: the onchange works,but when i picked 2017 value on select,the years starts from December 1902 and still can moved up to January 2018 @nounzor.

Comment: You have to look at datepicker DOCS to find how to set min and max Date, i didn't test my code, it was just to expose the logic of what you need to do

Comment: oohh sure i will look into it...@nounzor

Comment: What is you id_year when year=2017 ? Cause my method get the value => the id_year, maybe try to get the year instead